# Change of Cassandra Keyspace at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

Is there any possibility of changing the Cassandra keyspace at runtime using Spring Boot?
So far i have the code below but the problem is that i only have one Session bean:

```
@Bean
public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
    session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
    session.setKeyspaceName(getKeyspace());
    session.setConverter(converter());
    session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS); 
    session.getObject().execute("USE " + getKeyspace());
    return session;
}
```

So, actually the question is, can i have multiple beans like the one returned above and use them depending on a given keyspace or i can have one single session bean and switch there the keyspaces?
Can i have a handle to the returned bean and play with it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. I would setup a second `Session` bean annotated with `@Qualifier`

Comment: Ok, so this would be one approach, but lets say that i would like to do something more dynamic like using the same bean that i get from the method pasted above and then with that bean access the Session object and change the keyspace at runtime. Is that possible? What i would also want to find out is how Spring is using this bean and where?

Comment: Depending how you are using the session... Is it already connected to the database? Or are you connecting before each execution? You probably could update the keyspace before each execution if the session isn't already connected to cassandra, otherwise you are wasting CPU cycles disconnecting and updating keyspace and reconnecting. As a developer I my IMHO I would rather manage 2 session beans instead.

Comment: ok, i get the two or multiple sessions approach, and most likely this will be the preferred solution, but i was wondering if there is no way to use the just one session that changes the keyspace at runtime without disconnecting?

Comment: You can try... You would need to get the `session` been into your `dao` and then have it run `session.setKeyspaceName(getKeyspace());` and `session.getObject().execute("USE " + getKeyspace());` before every interaction with Cassandra. I would try it out, but grab some metrics around updating the keyspace everytime so you know how it will perform.